# What species of spider is this?

Tags: species-identification

I'm trying to find out what kind of spider is this little fellow:
[image: SPIDER!]

It really seems to like our garage and is the bane of my girlfriend (as evidenced by all the screaming when on two occasions one got into our home somehow). I was never able to spot this kind outdoors, which is rather odd (there are plenty of Araneus diadematus spiders in the area which are fairly easy to spot).

It's hard to tell on the photo, but these spiders seem rather big (at least as far as spiders in Poland I was able to spot go)... somewhere around 5cm at least (legs included)? They really do make for rather large, black spots against an otherwise white garage wall.

I'd really like to find what kind of species this is so that I can, hopefully, convince my GF that it's harmless to humans. Unless it isn't, in which case **I'll** start getting scared of walking into our garage. ;)

PS. We live in Poland, Poznań.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **giant house spider**, *Eratigena atrica* complex group. It could be one of the species of E.atrica, E.duellica, E.saevus. It is too dark for E.agrestis.

Eratigena is a genus spun-off from Tegenaria. But the other suggested answers of T.domestica is a spider that remains in the Tegenaria genus. This spider in the question does not exhibit the leg-bending (annulations) that are present in T.domestica.

The abdominal pattern is the classic 'herringbone' pattern that places this in Eratigena, while Tegenaria abdominal patterns are a different sort of a spotty pattern.

The habitat of giant house spiders overlaps fairly consistently with T.domestica - human-made structures, indoors, garages, etc.

Giant house spiders are typically larger than E.agrestis and T.domestica, particularly in their leg spans.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is just
[Tegenaria domestica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_domestica). I am from Czech republic and this is really big and kinde everywhere. Specialy in garages.

Comment: Just a minor note - it would be helpful if the link wasn't for the mobile version of Wikipedia and was for an English article...

Comment: I am sorry for that but I thought when you are from Poland u would prefer something a bit closer to your language.

Comment: Well, no offence, but those are still different languages. ;) Plus, this is StackExchange, which is English-based, AFAIK.

Comment: This is a giant house spider, not Tegenaria

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a European spider pro, so although I think it looks rather like a Tegenaria, I can't be positive it isn't something else that I'm unfamiliar with.

However, I can state confidently that it is not any of the problem biters known on Earth.  In Europe, you're going to be careful around any of the Black Widow group (Latrodectus spp.) and perhaps be cautious if you should come across a Mediterranean Recluse (Loxosceles rufescens) - but this isn't either of those possibilities.  Widows are small, globular cobweb spiders with relatively short, arched legs, and Recluses are very plain spiders with a dark central 'fiddle' mark on the 'head'.
By elimination, if it isn't any of the known problem biters, it's harmless.

However, what you can do to get a better identification, is to submit your photo to Ed Nieuwenhuys at [his website](http://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/Spiders/spidhome.htm) which deals with European spiders.